# Keycloak - Identity providers and clients

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to have different identity providers for each client on a realm or the identity providers are only realm-dependant? I would like for example to have github identity provider for one client and ldap for another, on the same realm, I have looked through the docs and the management console but no luck, before trying another thing just wanted to check im not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from the keycloak people, it is not possible to have client-dependant identity providers, so I need to create 2 realms for this.

Comment: Got the answer from their mail list: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/

Comment: Got it. I just joined the mail list. Thanks!